# Thread should complete all transactions before shuttingdown

Tags: jmeter

I am using ultimate thread group .Once the duration is completed, threads are getting shutdown abruptly without completing all transactions.
is there any way to let thread to complete all transactions before shutting down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work it around using [While Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/while-controller-jmeter).

1. Add While Controller to your Test Plan
2. Put all your requests sequence under the While Controller
3. Use the following [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) as the While Controller's "Condition"

   ```
   ${__groovy((System.currentTimeMillis() - (vars.get('TESTSTART.MS') as long)) < 5000,)}
   ```
4. Replace `5000` with the desired test duration in milliseconds
5. Add [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler after the While Controller and configure it to stop the current thread

[image]

As you can see despite Ultimate Thread Group is set to run for 1 hour the test duration was 5 seconds and all 3 Samplers were executed equal number of times.